# How to pause cmd window for 5 seconds using execwait in nsis?

Tags: nsis

I want to check the output of encrypted password using java utility jar file for that I added 5-second timeout

ExecWait  '"java.exe" -Ddata.dir="C:\example" -jar "encrypt.jar" "DecryptPassword" "5q/wsfafLx8vcsdsd==" "C:\temp.properties" & **timeout 5**'

but my cmd window gets closed automatically? how to stop the cmd window for 5 seconds to check output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` is not something that just works everywhere, it only works in the command interpreter. Add `cmd.exe /c if 1==1`  to the start of the ExecWait string.

A better solution is to use the nsExec plug-in to get the result from stdout.